# In the modern Planet of the Apes series, are there subtitles for the sign language?

Tags: subtitles, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

I just rented *War for the Planet of the Apes* on Google Play. If I watch without subtitles, there are quite long scenes purely in sign language, which feels a little odd. If I turn on the English subs, the sign language is subtitled (but so is the rest of the movie).

The movie has no [forced/non-english](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62723/what-is-the-term-used-to-refer-to-foreign-alien-language-only-subtitles-in-a-fil) subtitle track.

When screened properly, i.e. in a cinema in an English speaking country, are these scenes shown with or without subtitles?

Comment: I just watched this on blu-ray; and the sign language was subtitled as I expected. Sounds like something might be wrong with Google Play.

Comment: I didn’t see War in the theaters, but in the first movie of the reboot series, the sign language was definitely subtitled in the theater.

Comment: To be fair to Google Play, I reported it, and got a refund immediately. I wonder whether they'll fix the problem. It's surprising how often streaming services still get this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are shown with subtitles.   Screenshot embedded from the blu-ray:

[image: photograb]

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in an IMAX in India, and no there were no subtitles in the movie. I thought that this was a big mistake on the part of the studio and crew,
as key moments and conversations happened with sign language. I haven't bought it's Blu Ray, that might have forced subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

## In foreign cinemas, there are subtitles for the sign language.

I cannot speak for english-speaking countries, but at least in Portugal the movie's sign language was subbed. My source is that I watched the War for the Planet of the Apes in the cinema, almost 1 year ago.